# Can i bake Toon shader (Shader to RBG) to a texture?

Tags: modeling, texturing, shaders, baking

i made a cartoon model and now i need to create the textures to import to another game, but as you seen in the title, it's using Shader to RGB.

I tried to bake it with emission and emit in cycles but everything comes up black.

[image: body fo the model with shader to RGB]

Comment: You cannot bake shader-to-RGB, because it is unsupported by Cycles.  There are compositing tricks you can do, but they're not going to help you here, because a toon shader is going to be either view or lighting dependent or both.  Baking it will not give you anything that is view or lighting dependent.  If you're trying to import to a game engine or a game with shader modding support, you should be looking at recreating your toon material in that game's shaders.  If you're trying to import to an existing game with limited modding support, you're kind of out luck.

Comment: Aw, that's sad, well, thank you for replying anyways!