# How can I bake this colorramp data to the model's texture?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, texture-painting, texture-baking

As I said in the title for some reason I cant seem to bake the node to the texture. It just comes as a black texture.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello maybe pack your image and share your object (at least a part of it) so that we can try?

Comment: @moonboots Ive added the file. Im also trying to show up the black outline of the model in unity

Comment: Here Nathan says that you can't bake Shader-to RGB: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/258062/can-i-bake-toon-shader-shader-to-rbg-to-a-texture so it must be the problem here?

Comment: hmm I see thanks for the info

Comment: More like, you can bake it, but once baked it will not adapt to the lighting like the shader does.

Comment: so how can I bake it? I dont mind the adapting

Comment: nvm im dumb, it's an eevee only shader and you can't bake with eevee